# NURBS Library supporting trivariate NURBS

Tags: c++, c, fortran, nurbs

Does anyone know a free (as in free beer) C, C++ or even FORTRAN library that supports operations not only NURBS curves and surfaces but also Volumes (i.e. trivariate NURBS)?

I know about [open nurbs](http://www.opennurbs.org/), but as far as I know it does not support NURBS volumes (feel free to correct me on that, since my experiences with that library are somewhat limited).

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13712396/1413374. I didn't check if these support volumes, but I guess OpeCasCADe does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IRIT modelling environment](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~irit/) supports trivatiate spline volumes.

It is free, but only for non commercial uses. You can contact the developer and ask about the commercial licencing terms.

Answer (score 1):

The opennurbs ON_NurbsCage class is a trivariate NURBS "volume".

The declaration of the ON_NurbsCage class is in opennurbs_nurbssurface.h and the implementation is in opennurbs_nurbsvolume.h

ON_NurbsCage provide evaluation, bounding box, and iso surface extraction tools.

This information is for the 2013-07-11 version of opennurbs that is available from http://www.opennurbs.com

Answer (score 0):

The geometry module of [Gismo](https://github.com/gismo/gismo/wiki/About--G-Smo) may satisfy your need.